# FieldCustomizer extensions preventing GroupBy list details from rendering

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx-extension

I several lists with a View grouped by a Taxonomy term set with a Field customizer extension applied to the standard title field. When a user clicks on a specifc group in the Grouped by View to render the list with items from a specific group, the list will sometimes not render and only the list title is visible.

[image]

When the user refreshes the page, the content loads as expected. Also removing the extension allows the list to load normally. To rule out the issue being with our extension, I have tried replacing it with the HelloWorld extension demo at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer as well as upgrading the SPFx version used, but the issue persisted. Browser DEV tools and the Sharepoint Console are not reporting any errors, and I do not see any failed network requests that would indicate a server error such as returning too many fields/items, and the list I've been reproducing this on only has 6 items in it and the view is configured to display 17 fields

The View Query is pretty basic so I don't think the issue lies there

`<GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30"><FieldRef Name="Subcycle" /></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="TrackingId" /></OrderBy>`

I have tried removing a custom formatter and disabling the aggregate measure on the list for good measure. I have not been able to reproduce this issue on default sharepoint list, but I've run out of ideas to try and Isloate a root cuase. As best I can tell, the Field Customizer extension constructor never gets invoked when sharepoint transitions to the list view. Is there some other list property or sharepoint configuration that could be causing this issue that I may be overlooking, or am I perhaps seeing a sharepoint bug?